# PHP/MySQL Member System always gives me Email Already Registered

Tags: php, mysql, system, member

The member system code always redirect me to "email already registered page" 
Thats the code I use in processing to check whether the email, that will be the username, 
is already been taken or not 
please help!!!!

```
<?php
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "ms_admin";
    $db_pass = "secretpassword";
    $db_name = "member_system";

     $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        die("Databse connection failed." . mysqli_connect_error()
            . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")" );
?>

<?php

    function check_email($e_mail)
    {
        $query  = "SELECT email FROM members ";
        $query .= "WHERE email='$e_mail'";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($num_rows>0) header("Location: registration_successful.php");
         else header("Location: registration_unsuccessful.php");
    }
?>

<?php
    $full_name = ucwords($_POST["full_name"]);
    $email = strtolower($_POST["email"]);
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]);

    check_email($email);
?>
```

I changed those:

```
 if($num_rows>0) header("Location: registration_successful.php");
  else header("Location: registration_unsuccessful.php");
```

to:

```
 if($num_rows>0) header("Location: registration_unsuccessful.php");
  else header("Location: registration_successful.php");
```

It seems that ($num_rows>0) always return FALSE :(

please help,,
Thank you....

Comment: Where is this page email already registered?I see succesful or not

Comment: the: registration_unsuccessful.php

Comment: not sure if this is a typo but you have not appended the `where` condition to the main query. just replaced the query altogether.

Comment: thats ok, this is considered as one line:
die("Databse connection failed." . mysqli_connect_error()
            . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")" );

Comment: Stealth edit,really nice.And leave a space after members

Comment: Echo  $num_rows,what is the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$connection variable is missing in check_email() please set `global $connection;` for db connection like

```
function check_email($e_mail){
        global $connection;
        $query  = "SELECT email FROM members ";
        $query .= "WHERE email='$e_mail'";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($num_rows>0) header("Location: registration_successful.php");
         else header("Location: registration_unsuccessful.php");
     }


     check_email($email);
```

OR

```
 function check_email($e_mail, $connection){
    $query  = "SELECT email FROM members ";
    $query .= "WHERE email='$e_mail'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows>0) header("Location: registration_successful.php");
     else header("Location: registration_unsuccessful.php");
 }


 check_email($email, $connection);
```

Though i like 1st one :)

Comment: NO, See $connection  is Global scope variable as its Not defined in Any function , its defined at  the top.

Comment: You dont need to pass $connection variable anywhere . Its globally accessible withing any function without supplynig it.Getting?

Comment: I have same issue when i run this code in my localhost. Its working when use the ways i mentioned. i think global $connection; need if all code in same page

Comment: Why should it be ? Consider defining global variable Without `global` keyword , You can access it in That inner function ? Yes , then there shold not be any issue with  $connection variable.If anything happens , It will throw error and connection wont happen,then it will HALT code execution.Its not happening in OP's case ,so its not connection issue,.

Comment: its produce an Warning " Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given ... .."  will you please explain me the reason.

Comment: Yes sorry , IN function use `global $connection;` , as its better than passing in function and Alredy we have defined $connection at top.OR define -> $GLOBALS['connection']=WhatEver and access it in code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the test before you redirect the user :

```
// if the rows are > 0 then it means the email already exists 
// which means we should redirect to the unsuccessful registration page
if($num_rows>0) header("Location: registration_unsuccessful.php");
     else echo header("Location: registration_successful.php");
// else, we redirect to successful registration page (meaning the email does not exists in DB)
```

and as @Mihai mentioned, you forgot to concatenate your query string.

Comment: which means we still missing another error, can you use var_dump on  `$num_rows` so we can see what it contains ?

Answer (score 0):

> Try below code

```
<?php

function check_email($e_mail)
{
    $query = "SELECT email FROM members";
    $query .= "WHERE email='$e_mail'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows>0) header("Location: registration_unsuccessful.php");
     else echo header("Location: registration_successful.php")
}
?>

<?php
$full_name = ucwords($_POST["full_name"]);
$email = strtolower($_POST["email"]);
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);

check_email($email);
?>
```

Comment: Please explain what changes you made?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.JAVA.net: concatenate the query and change the if($num_rows) condition :)

Comment: I did reverse them, now anything "registration successful"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    $query  = "SELECT email FROM members ";
    $query .= "WHERE email='".$e_mail."'";
```

You missed Space after members , copy paste it in your code.

OR use simple solution

```
    $query  = "SELECT email FROM members WHERE email='".$e_mail."'";
```

**Update**

```
mysqli_store_result($connection);
$num_rows= mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
if($num_rows>0)
```

Reason -> 
Use store_result for buffering the result.

Comment: i fixed that, also still have the same problem :(

Comment: Did you try 2nd solution i told ?